# binarySearch method issue, not accepting int parameter

Tags: java

I am using the Java 2 Platform to practice different algorithms.  I am getting two errors and I think the first one is that I am passing the integer "5" from `arrayList[]` and getting an error.  The second problem is that I am getting an error in the main method when I call `binarySearch();`.  Do I need to put arrayList as the parameter for `binarySearch(arrayList)`?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinarySearch {

 int arrayList[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

 public static int binarySearch(int[] arrayList[],int 5)
 {
  int low = 0;
  int high = arrayList.length - 1;
  int mid = 0;

  while(low<=high)
  {
   mid = (low+high)/2;
   if(arrayList[mid].compareTo(searchObj)<0)
    low = mid + 1;
   else if (arrayList[mid].compareTo(searchObj)>0)
   {
    high = mid -1;
   }
   else 
    return mid;
  }
  return -1;

 }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  binarySearch();

 }

}
```

Comment: You need to buy a good beginners’ Java books that explains the difference between method definitions and method calls.

Comment: are there any that you have found helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point of declaration of the BinarySearch method you need this:

```
  public static int binarySearch(int[] arrayList,int searchObj){

     ///rest of your method
```

That is, you are searching for searchObj in the arrayList.

Then to call the method you provide the value for arrayList and searchObj. Like this:

```
 binarySearch(arrayLIst, 5);
```

Comment: You need arrayList without [] in the declaration.

Comment: Thanks @mr.Flamer. That's copy and paste for you.

Comment: thanks, that is what I needed.  Unfortunately, it looks like one can't use compareTo method with int so I need to make some modifications to get a binarySearch to work.

Comment: You can simply use if(arrayList[mid] > searchObj) etc.

Comment: I made some changes and the code works now but i get some numbers that I don't understand when I plug in an parameter that is outside of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax of function is

> public static int
>   binarySearch(ArrayList arrayList,int
>   searchbj=5)

also when using ArrayList use

> arrayList.get(index)

for retrieving

> arrayList.set(index)

for seting